# Square brackets in String.prototype.search() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

Something strange seems to happen when you use square brackets in a search phrase with [String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

```
var text = 'the needle in a [haystick]';
var result1 = text.search('[the] needle');   // 2
var result2 = text.search('[the]needle');    // -1
var result3 = text.search('[haystick]');     // 0
var result4 = text.search('\\[haystick\\]'); // 16
var result5 = text.search('[');              // SyntaxError: Unterminated character class .
```

It seems to work right if I escape the bracket with `\\`. But why?

Comment: `[the]` is a character class in RegEx. `"\\[the\\]"` parses it as `/\[the\]/` which escapes the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a string as a parameter in String.prototype.search(), this string is always converted to a regular expression.

```
var result1 = text.search('[the] needle');
```

is identical to

```
var result1 = text.search(/[the] needle/);
```

In order to search for a string, you have to use [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var result3 = text.indexOf('[haystick]');     // 16
```